# trying to count numbers that inside of a variable

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to count how many numbers inside of a variable. Here is the regex that i use..

```
preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $password, $numbers, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

When I try to get all numbers one by one, I use:

```
print_r($this->filter->password_filter($data["user_password"]));
```

user_password is 123d4sd6789. Result is an empty array.

```
Array ( )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can easily do it using `preg_split`:

```
$temp = preg_split('/\d/', $password);
$numCount = count($temp) - 1;
```

Your regex is flawed, since you're trying to count the number of digits in a password, using:

```
/[^0-9]/
```

Won't cut it, perhpas you meant to write:

```
/[0-9]/
```

Because what you have now matches *everything EXCEPT* a number.

There are a great number of ways to do what you're trying to do, I've benchmarked 4 different approaches, and found that using regex is the fastest approach. Using the bundled pcre extension that PHP ships with, `preg_split` outperforms all other approaches ~70% of the time, 20% of the time, the loops are faster, though, and ~10% `preg_match_all` is fastest.
On codepad, who don't use the standard PCRE for some reason, `preg_match_all` doesn't work, nor did `shuffle` prove to be reliable, so I added a `knuth` method, and I decided to test the differences between `/\d/` and `/[0-9]/` in combination with `preg_split` instead. On codepad, regex is faster >95% of the time as a result.
*In short*: use `preg_split` + regex for the best results.

Anyway, here's the benchmark code. It may seem silly to put it all into a class, but really, it's the *fair* way to benchmark. The string that is processed is kept in memory, as are all the arrays that are used to time the functions, and compare speeds.
I'm not calling the test methods directly, either, but use a `timeCall` method instead, simply because I want the garbage collector to GC what needs to be GC'ed after each call. Anyway, it's not too difficult to figure this code out, and it's the results that matter

```
class Bench
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $str = '123d4sd6789';

    private $functions = array(
        'regex' => null,
        'regex2' => null,
        'loop' => null,
        'loop2' => null
    );

    private $random = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->random = array_keys($this->functions);
        if (!shuffle($this->random)) $this->knuth();
    }

    /**
     * Knuth shuffle
     */
    private function knuth()
    {
        for ($i=count($this->random)-1,$j=mt_rand(0,$i);$i>0;$j=mt_rand(0,--$i))
        {
            $temp = $this->random[$j];
            $this->random[$j] = $this->random[$i];
            $this->random[$i] = $temp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call all functions in random order, timing each function
     * determine fastest approach, and echo results
     * @param $randomize
     * @return string
     */
    public function test($randomize)
    {
        if ($randomize) if (!shuffle($this->random)) $this->knuth();
        foreach($this->random as $func) $this->functions[$func] = $this->timeCall($func);
        $fastest = array('f', 100000);
        foreach($this->functions as $func => $time)
        {
            $fastest = $fastest[1] > $time ? array($func, $time) : $fastest;
            echo 'Function ', $func, ' took ', $time, 'ms', PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo 'Fastest approach: ', $fastest[0], ' (', $fastest[1], 'ms)', PHP_EOL;
        return $fastest[0];
    }

    /**
     * Time function call
     * @param string $func
     * @return float mixed
     */
    private function timeCall($func)
    {
        echo $func, PHP_EOL;
        $start = microtime(true);
        $this->{$func}();
        return (microtime(true) - $start);
    }

    /**
     * Count digits in string using preg_split
     * @return int
     */
    private function regex()
    {
        return count(preg_split('/\d/', $this->str)) - 1;
    }

    /**
     * count digits in string using str_split + is_numeric + loop
     * @return int
     */
    private function loop()
    {
        $chars = str_split($this->str);
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($chars as $char) if (is_numeric($char)) ++$counter;
        return $counter;
    }

    /**
     * count digits by iterating over string, using is_numeric
     * @return int
     */
    private function loop2()
    {
        for($i=0,$j=strlen($this->str),$counter=0;$i<$j;++$i) if (is_numeric($this->str{$i})) ++$counter;
        return $counter;
    }

    /**
     * use preg_split + [0-9] instead of \d
     * @return int
     */
    private function regex2()
    {
        return count(preg_split('/[0-9]/', $this->str)) - 1;
        if (preg_match_all('/[0-9]/',$this->str, $matches)) return count($matches);
        return 0;
    }

}


$benchmark = new Bench();
$totals = array();
for($i=0;$i<10;++$i)
{
    $func = $benchmark->test($i);
    if (!isset($totals[$func])) $totals[$func] = 0;
    ++$totals[$func];
    if ($i < 9) echo PHP_EOL, '---------------------------------------------', PHP_EOL;
}
var_dump($totals);
```

[Here's the codepad I set up](http://codepad.org/aqgaTt3S)

Comment: when I use /[0-9]/ result: "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 ) )"

Comment: @Yusuf: how did you use `/[0-9]/`? with `preg_match`? because I'm using `preg_split` and `count` the size of the resulting array (-1), which, when applied to `123d4sd6789` gives the expected result: 8

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want a regex?

```
$arr1 = str_split($password);
$counter=0;
foreach($arr1 as $v){
  if(is_numeric($v))$counter++;
}
```

Comment: Well, OP might want to use regex here, because your approach is actually _slower_: You're constructing an array, then assigning each char to `$v`, and call `is_numeric` on that variable. That's just too much. I've done some benchmarking, and added the benchmark script to my answer

Comment: Wow thanks for the insight. I always thought that regular expressions were pretty slow in php.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all` to select all the numbers:

```
$reg = '/[0-9]/';
$string = '123d4sd6789';

preg_match_all($reg, $string, $out);
echo (count($out[0]));
```

Comment: But It returns 1. Because there is a array inside of array.

Comment: That's why i added `[0]` here is a demo showing how it works (select preg_match_all tab) http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2Qi

Comment: @Yusuf: You might want to check my updated answer, I've added some details on various approaches on how to do what you're trying to do + did some benchmarking